# Java-Continueing Object Moment-Should I Just Add a Method Instead of a Class?

Tags: java, image, user-interface, keyboard, move

So I am working on a Arcade shooting game, and I am currently working on a shooting class. This class creates a new bullet and fires it using an oval class. I have another class called playervsplayer that calls the shooting class when ever space bar is pressed. This bullet to continue moving regardless if space bar is pressed again. Please help me make my current code work as I am just going to work with key listener for this project and not key binding. If you do not want to work with key binding, then please do not respond.  I know the up and down directions both have 2, when it will just be 1 up and 1 down, I will fix that later so just ignore that silly thing for now. I have tried requesting focus in both classes, but did not help as it still stops if I press the spacebar again. If I do not press the spacebar again, it works fine. Here is the code for the shooting class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Shooting implements ActionListener{
    private Sprite ship1;
    private Sprite ship2;
    private int win_size;
    private int bullet_size=20;//max of bullet size of 20 and min of 1
    private JFrame window;
    private Oval bullet;
    private final int stop1=0;
    private final int stop2=1;
    private final int up1=2;
    private final int up2=3;
    private final int down1=4;
    private final int down2=5;
    private int dir1=stop1;
    private int dir2=stop2;
    private int bullet_speed=5;
    private Timer timer;
    private Color bullet_color=Color.green;
    public Shooting(JFrame w,Sprite s1,Sprite s2,int w_size) {
        window=w;
        ship1=s1;
        ship2=s2;
        win_size=w_size;
    }
    public void shotmain(int firing_from) {
        timer = new Timer( 10, this );
        timer.start();
        if (firing_from==1) {//So assuming fired from ship1 or player 1 on the bottom of the screen and not the top of the screen
            int shipx_loc=ship1.getX();
            int shipy_loc=ship1.getY();
            int ship_width=ship1.getWidth();
            int ship_height=ship1.getHeight();
            bullet=new Oval(shipx_loc+(int)(ship_width/2)-(bullet_size/2)+1,shipy_loc,bullet_size,bullet_size);//Yes, I need the plus 1 or else its not quite center, I am picky I know.
            bullet.setBackground(bullet_color);
            window.add(bullet,0);
            window.repaint();
            dir1=up1;
        }
    }
    private void move_bullet() {
        boolean bob=true;
        if (dir1==up1) {
            if (bullet.getY()<=50) {//for now
                window.remove(bullet);
                window.repaint();
            }
            else {
                bullet.setLocation(bullet.getX(),bullet.getY()-bullet_speed);
            }
        }
        else if (dir2==down2) {
            if (bullet.getY()>=win_size-50) {//for now
                window.remove(bullet);
                window.repaint();
            }
            else {
                bullet.setLocation(bullet.getX(),bullet.getY()+bullet_speed);
            }
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ( e.getSource() == timer ){
            move_bullet();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the code for the playervsplayer class:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class PlayervsPlayer implements KeyListener,ActionListener{

    private JFrame window;
    private Timer timer;
    private Shooting shot;
    private int win_size;
    private int ship_clearence=45;
    private int speed=3;
    private final int stop1=0;
    private final int stop2=1;
    private final int left1=2;
    private final int left2=3;
    private final int right1=4;
    private final int right2=5;
    private int dir1=stop1;
    private int dir2=stop2;
    private Sprite ship1=new Sprite("Spaceship.png");
    private Sprite ship2=new Sprite("Spaceship2.png");

    public PlayervsPlayer(JFrame w,int win_s) {
        window=w;
        win_size=win_s;
        window.addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void pvpmain() {
        ship1.setSize(125,125);
        ship1.setLocation((int)((win_size/2)-(ship1.getWidth()/2)),win_size-ship1.getHeight()-ship_clearence);
        ship2.setSize(125,125);
        ship2.setLocation((int)((win_size/2)-(ship1.getWidth()/2)),0);
        window.add(ship1,0);
        window.add(ship2,0);
        window.repaint();
        shot=new Shooting(window,ship1,ship2,win_size);
        timer = new Timer( 10, this );
        timer.start();
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key=e.getKeyCode();
        if ( key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT ){
            dir1 = right1;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            dir1=left1;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            shot.shotmain(1);
        }
        if (key==KeyEvent.VK_Q) {
            dir2=left2;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            dir2=right2;
        }
        else if (key==KeyEvent.VK_E) {
            //Nothing for now as for shooting
        }
    }
    private void move() {
        if (dir1==left1) {
            if (ship1.getX()<=speed) {
                dir1=stop1;
            }
            else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX()-speed,ship1.getY());
            }
        }
        else if (dir1==right1) {
            if (ship1.getX()+ship1.getWidth()>=win_size-speed) {
                dir1=stop1;
            }
            else {
                ship1.setLocation(ship1.getX()+speed,ship1.getY());
            }
        }
        if (dir2==left2) {
            if (ship2.getX()<=speed) {
                dir2=stop2;
            }
            else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX()-speed,ship2.getY());
            }
        }
        else if (dir2==right2) {
            if (ship2.getX()+ship2.getWidth()>=win_size-speed) {
                dir2=stop2;
            }
            else {
                ship2.setLocation(ship2.getX()+speed,ship2.getY());
            }
        }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ( e.getSource() == timer ){
            move();
        }

    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        //Nothing

    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        //Nothing

    }


}
```

I have many other classes, but these are the 2 most relevant classes as what I need to add will be in one of the two classes. No errors are being generated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone knows please or answer.